# Exhausting Curl's Sockets in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I'm doing high volumes of API calls to a server using the CURL library in a PHP CLI script.

I noticed after 28,219 connections (sequentially opened/executed, not concurrently) curl fails. Every subsequent request that is attempted, fails until about 30 seconds later.

The API that is being accessed (as far as I can tell) is not hanging or causing errors. I've attempted this with different remote hosts being accessed, and the error always happens, so I suspect the issue is with PHP/Curl, and not the remote host.

Here's a sample script I made to demonstrate the issue:

```
try {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
        get('https://example.org/'); // change me if you're going to run this
        echo '.';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error happened on {$i} - {$e->getMessage()}";
}

function get($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    if (! $curl) {
        throw new Exception('Error1 - Could not create new curl handle');
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    $contents = curl_exec($curl);
    $info     = curl_getinfo($curl);

    if ($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
        throw new Exception("Error2 " . curl_strerror($errno), $errno);
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($info['http_code'] === 200) {
        return $contents;
    }

    throw new Exception("Error3", (int) $info['http_code']);
}
```

Output:

> .........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Error happened on 28219 - Error2 Couldn't connect to server

I'm inclined to believe this error is happening because I've exhausted the available TCP sockets, but I'm not familiar enough with how that works to know a proper solution to this problem (short of making fewer requests).

Edit:

Since people keep suggesting it's the remote server, here's the result of siege doing 1000000 requests to my test server (the one with the API). I'm not 100% sure what caused the single failured, but it only happened once, so I'll take it as an anomaly, unlike the consistent failures I've gotten from CURL after 28,219 requests.

```
siege -c 1 -r 1000000 http://mytestserver/same/url/as/with/curl
* SIEGE 3.0.5
** Preparing 1 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
The server is now under siege...[error] socket: -187603200 connection refused.: Connection refused

done.

Transactions:             999999 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             626.70 secs
Data transferred:         7719.03 MB
Response time:            0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         1595.66 trans/sec
Throughput:               12.32 MB/sec
Concurrency:              0.94
Successful transactions:  999999
Failed transactions:      1
Longest transaction:      0.14
Shortest transaction:     0.00
```

Comment: Please show us more detailed what the error is you get

Comment: probably being blocked -- that's a lot of requests, consider adding a sleep statement

Comment: @self Blocked by what? The remote server is not blocking the requests, I'm able to run siege on it doing many multiples of the requests I'm doing without any issue.

Comment: "Couldn't connect to server" actually suggests that the server end is rejecting the many connects... if curl itself would run out of sockets, it would be likely to return another error

Comment: *Hm...*, any way you can setup a count in a conditional statement, set to a certain (high) number you think it will break, and exit on it? Changing that number to a higher one after. I can't fix your problem but that's what I'd do to try and figure out at how many calls it would take for it to fail/stop. @Ian

Comment: The number seems to always be 28219 (if I wait 30 seconds between tests).

Comment: Hope it is your own server. Run netstat on the client and on the server to see if there are too many TCP connections in wait state.

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/48717/practical-maximum-open-file-descriptors-ulimit-n-for-a-high-volume-system and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608775/max-number-of-sockets-for-php-stream-socket-client see if those Q&A's help. *Being quick finds*.

Comment: This is my own dev server, so slamming it is fine. I was hoping someone might have info on how CURL uses sockets in PHP, and if an open/closed CURL connection frees up the available sockets or not. I want to make sure people realize I'm doing sequential (not concurrent) connections. They get opened, then closed right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your making a new curl resource each iteration. If you re use the connection everything should work as intended. Initialize curl out of the loop and pass in the curl variable

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize you could re-use a curl handle multiple times. I'm guessing this can only be done if the URL doesn't change, right?

Comment: No but more benifits are given to a single site which supports keep alive requests curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");